# How to set route for a rendered action? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

i'm new to mvc, rails and web development and i'm facing a problem:

I have an action(show) and a view for this action.

The view for show submits a form_tag to another action, that renders the action show.

The problem is, I have no idea how to set a route for the action that renders show.

Right now my `routes.rb` is:

```
resources :meals do
  collection do
    get "meals/:id", to: "meals#show"
  end
end
```

Tried to add these but didn't work:

```
match "meals/:id/calculate" , :to => "meals#calculate",:via => [:get]
```

and:

```
get "meals/:id/calculate", to => "meals#calculate"
```

Comment: Can you add your relevant controller and view pages ?

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? And as dkp stated ... your controller and view would be helpful. Your output from `rake routes` would be useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resources :meals` generate path to `show` action. 
Run `rake routes` or open in a browser 'http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` to see list of generated routes.

To add `calculate` use member:

```
resources :meals do
  get :calculate, on: :member
end
```